# use amazon s3 to upload a image when there are multiple input in a form

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, multer

I have installed multer, multer-s3 and aws-sdk and try to upload a profile image when a user upload a profile picture.

so far I have the code below in a file call file_upload.js

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk')

const multer = require('multer')
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3')

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: "my access key",
    accessKeyId: "my key id",
    region: "us-east-2"
})
const s3 = new aws.S3()

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'user-image1',
    acl: 'public-read',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: 'TESTING-META-DATA'});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
  })
})

module.exports = upload
```

and a post request when user choose some input

```
const upload = require('../assets/file-upload')
const singleUpload = upload.single('image')

router.post("/edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: id },
    {
      $set: { 
        education: req.body.education,
        language: req.body.language,
        bio: req.body.bio,
        image_file: req.body.image_file
      },
    },
    { new: true },
    (err, result) => {
      res.redirect("/dashboard");
    }
  );
});
```

in my ejs, all the String input was handle correctly when user input the data, except for image.

```
<div class="upload-btn-img">
        <input type="file" name="image_file" onchange="showThumbnail(this)" />
 </div>
```

My question is, how can i save a photo with all the other input? all the other input is store in mongodb atlas, and images needs to store in amazon s3. the url need to be store in mongodb atlas under field named image_file.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a middleware that intercept the request and send the file to s3, which then returns the url.

Here is an example i did a while back this is the 
--Controller https://github.com/C0D1NGD0J0/weareunited4life/blob/master/app/Controllers/upload.js)

--Route
router.post("/", passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), uploadImg, postCntrl.create);

Pay attention to the "uploadImg" middleware, it must come before the controller action that save the document.